# Qt QGridLayout - removing item spacing

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to write an implementation of battleship in Qt and I am using two QGridLayouts for containing QToolButtons that are used to represent players' grids. The top-level layout (QMainWindows one) is a QHBoxLayout. What I want to accomplish is to remove the spacing between these buttons. This is how it's looking at the moment:

[image: Grid]

It definitely isn't pretty. I am adding items into these layouts like this:

```
QIcon icon;
icon.addFile(QStringLiteral(":/images/Resources/field_blue.png"), QSize(), QIcon::Normal, QIcon::Off);
for (int i = 0; i < dimensions; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dimensions; ++j)
    {
        QToolButton* buttonLeft = new QToolButton(this);
        buttonLeft->setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon);
        buttonLeft->setText(QString::number(i) + "-" + QString::number(j));
        buttonLeft->setFixedSize(FIELD_ICON_SIZE + 10, FIELD_ICON_SIZE + 10); // FIELD_ICON_SIZE -> 20
        buttonLeft->setIcon(icon);
        buttonLeft->setIconSize(QSize(FIELD_ICON_SIZE, FIELD_ICON_SIZE));
        buttonLeft->setAutoRaise(true);
        QToolButton* buttonRight = new QToolButton(this);
        buttonRight->setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon);
        buttonRight->setText(QString::number(i) + "-" + QString::number(j));
        buttonRight->setFixedSize(FIELD_ICON_SIZE + 10, FIELD_ICON_SIZE + 10);
        buttonRight->setIcon(icon);
        buttonRight->setIconSize(QSize(FIELD_ICON_SIZE, FIELD_ICON_SIZE));
        buttonRight->setAutoRaise(true);
        _ui.gridLayoutLeft->addWidget(buttonLeft, i, j);
        _ui.gridLayoutRight->addWidget(buttonRight, i, j);
    }
}
```

I could try using spacers but they leave blank spots which is also not desirable.

Comment: `QGridLayout::setSpacing(0)`?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Looks like this, now - http://i.imgur.com/Of7Qjf7.png

Comment: @mhcuervo I am trying to get rid of the spaces between those buttons with blue icons that are supposed to represent fields in players' grids. I want to make these grids look like single planes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As almost always in programming there are several ways of achieving what you want, so I'll give you my solution which is just another one.
If you want to use "buttons" as tiles for your game, you will need to strong-style them, not only make them look the way you want for a specific theme in a specific platform, which is what you're doing now. The default style for `QToolButton`s is not the same on Mac, Windows, Linux nor the behavior of the auto-rising effect. That's why I recommend to take full control of the button style.
I'll include a very basic example you can use to get some ideas and put them in your application.

First I decided to use `QPushButton`s instead of `QToolButton`s. The code for populating the left side grid would be like follows:

```
// ...
for (int i = 0; i < dimensions; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dimensions; ++j)
    {
        QPushButton* buttonLeft = new QPushButton(this);
        buttonLeft->setFixedSize(20, 20);
        QToolButton* buttonRight = new QToolButton(this);
        ui->gridLayoutLeft->addWidget(buttonLeft, i + 1, j + 1);

        // ...

    }
}
```

Notice that I've changed the indexes when adding the buttons to the grid. This is because I will reserve the first row and the first column for the spacers I'll use later to shrink the buttons.

Now, lets set the layout spacing to zero:

```
ui->gridLayoutLeft->setSpacing(0);
```

and add the spacers:

[image]

```
    // Vertical spacers
    ui->gridLayoutLeft->addItem(new QSpacerItem(20, 40, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding), 0, 0, 1, dimensions + 2);
    ui->gridLayoutLeft->addItem(new QSpacerItem(20, 40, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding), dimensions + 1, 0, 1, dimensions + 2);

    // Horizontal spacers
    ui->gridLayoutLeft->addItem(new QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Minimum), 1, 0, dimensions, 1);
    ui->gridLayoutLeft->addItem(new QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Minimum), 1, dimensions + 1, dimensions, 1);
```

The buttons are now as joint as they can.

[image]

Finally the buttons need to be styled. To do that I prefer to use style sheets. (A lot of information about style sheets can be found in the Qt documentation: [The Style Sheet Syntax](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html), [Qt Style Sheets Reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html), [Qt Style Sheets Examples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html))

```
QString styleSheet =
    "QPushButton {"
    "  background-color: blue;"
    "  border: none;"
    "}"
    "QPushButton:hover {"
      "background-color: lightblue;"
    "}"
    "QPushButton:pressed {"
      "background-color: red;"
    "}";
setStyleSheet(styleSheet);
```

The result of this simple style sheet is:

[image]
[image]

You can play with it until you get a nice behavior, you can even simulate the auto-raising effect but the most important fact is that with this approach your game board should look exactly the same on all Qt supported platforms.

Comment: Kinda funny, I was just looking at this again and ready to post an answer that would not have been nearly as pretty as yours so instead I can just vote for yours. :)  If you do stick with QToolButton the one other thing you'll need to do is get rid of `setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)`.  Otherwise, the important part is "border: none;" in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

You made the buttons size bigger than icon size.

```
buttonLeft->setFixedSize(FIELD_ICON_SIZE + 10, FIELD_ICON_SIZE + 10)
buttonLeft->setIconSize(QSize(FIELD_ICON_SIZE, FIELD_ICON_SIZE));
```

By the way, `QToolButton` is used for `QToolBar`. Why don't you use `QPushButton`, instead?

Sorry, at first I want to wirte the above by comment, but my reputation is too low(^^;)

You can call `setSpacing(0)` but the spacing varys by the size of the GQridLayout. So `setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize)` also necessary(then you cannot change the size of widget, maybe).
This approach works with `QPushButton`, but not with `QToolButton`. It seems that there's some padding inside of `QToolButton` code(the size of icon seems smaller than setting - `FIELD_ICON_SIZE * FIELD_ICON_SIZE`).

Comment: I use QToolButton because of the "setAutoRaise" method. Btw, it looks like this when I change like you suggested - http://i.imgur.com/Of7Qjf7.png